# Integers not being printed in NSLOG

Tags: objective-c, nslog

```
NSLOG("your current number of users is:%@",userNumber);
```

this doesn't print the userNumber which is 5(i checked in debugging mode).
any advices?

Comment: change %@ to %d. And the function is named NSLog, not NSLOG

Comment: My main advice would be to read the documentation.

Comment: Xcode tells you in a warning that this is wrong; if you click on the little warning sign on the left, it will fix it for you automatically.

Comment: oh yes i forgot about the %d you are right

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage is:

```
NSLog(@"Your number is: %d",userNumber);
```

Comment: why? what is the diffrence

Comment: See for yourself! (it is ``NSLog``, not ``NSLOG``, and to include an integer you have to use ``%d`` instead of ``%@``, it for strings)